# Unable to install IHaskel kernel into Jupyter: "could not parse version number"

Tags: ipython, jupyter, ihaskell

I've recently completed the installation instructions for Haskell, and have reached the [final step](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/README.md#run-ihaskell) where I run

```
ihaskell install
```

to install the IHaskell kernel into Jupyter. However at this point I'm stuck, with the error

```
Detected IPython, but could not parse version number.
ihaskell: 
Ran commands: 
which ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython --version
which /usr/local/bin/ipython

Exception: ExitFailure 1
```

which makes no sense, since when I run those commands myself, I get a valid (and required) version number:

```
$ which ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython

$ /usr/local/bin/ipython --version
4.0.0

$ which /usr/local/bin/ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
```

How do I proceed to install the IHaskell kernel into Jupyter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a (soon to be addressed) [limitation of the current version](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/issues/553) of IHaskell, which only supports IPhython 3.0.

Stepping back to 3.0 with

```
pip uninstall ipython
pip uninstall jupyter_core
pip install ipython[notebook]==3.0
```

will resolve the problem until IHaskell is updated, at which point it will be safe to restore the current version of IPython with

```
pip install ipython[notebook] --upgrade
```

Note that stepping back to 3.0 will result in view visible differences, though the expected location of settings files will change.